# QGIS explode takes forever

Tags: qgis, explode

I'm doing a project on accessibility analysis in Hannover using QGIS 3.26.1 and everything went well. Creating a service area was ok, but when I use the explode function, the loading bar just shows an infinite progress. Any idea?

Edit 23:34 CEST: Finally showed up some progress, but it says it's gonna take thousands of minutes. My service area of lines almost covers the entire Hannover, is that a reason why it takes that long?

Comment: What explode function? Where is it

Comment: What data format are you using?

Comment: Everything's in gpkg, I generated a service area from a gpkg of points on a road network and when I explode this service area (lines), it takes very long

Comment: Do you need to have every line split into two point lines, which would seem to be a major undertaking,  or do you just need to convert multipart lines to singlepart, and/or just need to split lines/roads at their intersections which would likely be much easier?